# Break out of loop after checking the command of 120 seconds

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

```
nmap_vm(){ 
    while (( SECONDS < 120 )); do

        sshportactive=$(nmap $kernel_ipv4 -PN -p ssh | egrep 'open|closed|filtered' | awk '{print $2}')
            if [[ $sshportactive == open ]]; then
            $(setup_vm)
            break
            fi
            $(failed_VM)
    done

}
```

I am trying to launch multiple VMs and check if their ssh port is open or not. How continuously keep on checking for **sshportactive == open** till 120 seconds.

Like if the value is achieved before 120 seconds it breaks and executes **$(setup_vm)** & if the value is not == to open till 120 sec we break the loop and execute **$(failed_VM)**

**EDIT 1**

> I tried as you said, but it does not wait for 120s (I am posting a
> sample code below, the IPs we will be fetching from another function
> in production)

```
funA(){

    #Now we nmap to check if the SSH is Working or Not
    t_start=$SECONDS

    while (( (SECONDS - t_start) < 10 )); do
        if nmap $1 -PN -p ssh -oG - | grep -q '22/open/tcp'; then
            echo " This VM is Working Properly $2"
            return 0
        fi
        sleep 1
    done

    # we only get here if the loop exits without the port being open
    echo "This VM is not working $2"
    return 1
}

funB(){

        funA 172.105.252.241 lol
        funA 192.46.213.31 lol
}
```

We get output as :

```
bash -x g.sh 
+ funB
+ funA 172.105.252.241 lol
+ t_start=0
+ ((  (SECONDS - t_start) < 10  ))
+ nmap 172.105.252.241 -PN -p ssh -oG -
+ grep -q 22/open/tcp
+ echo ' This VM is Working Properly lol'
 This VM is Working Properly lol
+ return 0
+ funA 192.46.213.31 lol
+ t_start=0
+ ((  (SECONDS - t_start) < 10  ))
+ nmap 192.46.213.31 -PN -p ssh -oG -
+ grep -q 22/open/tcp
+ sleep 1
+ ((  (SECONDS - t_start) < 10  ))
+ nmap 192.46.213.31 -PN -p ssh -oG -
+ grep -q 22/open/tcp
+ sleep 1
+ ((  (SECONDS - t_start) < 10  ))
+ nmap 192.46.213.31 -PN -p ssh -oG -
+ grep -q 22/open/tcp
+ sleep 1
+ ((  (SECONDS - t_start) < 10  ))
+ nmap 192.46.213.31 -PN -p ssh -oG -
+ grep -q 22/open/tcp
+ sleep 1
+ ((  (SECONDS - t_start) < 10  ))
+ echo 'This VM is not working lol'
This VM is not working lol
+ return 1
```

**EDIT 2**

> I am posting it directly from the script used in production

```
ipv4_11011_22022="192.46.209.19"
ipv4_33033_44044_10101="45.79.121.184"
ipv4_55055_10001_20002="172.105.47.73"
ipv4_20202_30303_40404_50505_30033="172.105.58.123"
ipv4_30003_40004_50005="172.105.34.152"
ipv4_10011_20022_40044="45.79.124.118"
ipv4_50055_11111="172.105.48.47"
ipv4_22222_33333="172.105.51.44"
ipv4_44444_55555="172.105.253.130"
ipv4_KERNEL="172.105.42.211"
VM1_LABEL="11011_22022"
VM2_LABEL="33033_44044_10101"
VM3_LABEL="55055_10001_20002"
VM4_LABEL="20202_30303_40404_50505_30033"
VM5_LABEL="30003_40004_50005"
VM6_LABEL="10011_20022_40044"
VM7_LABEL="50055_11111"
VM8_LABEL="22222_33333"
VM9_LABEL="44444_55555"
VMK_LABEL="KERNEL"


healthcheck(){


    nmap $ipv4_11011_22022 $VM1_LABEL
    nmap $ipv4_33033_44044_10101 $VM2_LABEL
    nmap $ipv4_55055_10001_20002 $VM3_LABEL
    nmap $ipv4_20202_30303_40404_50505_30033 $VM4_LABEL
    nmap $ipv4_30003_40004_50005 $VM5_LABEL
    nmap $ipv4_10011_20022_40044 $VM6_LABEL
    nmap $ipv4_50055_11111 $VM7_LABEL
    nmap $ipv4_22222_33333 $VM8_LABEL
    nmap $ipv4_44444_55555 $VM9_LABEL
    nmap $ipv4_KERNEL $VMK_LABEL

}


nmap(){
    #Now we nmap to check if the SSH is Working or Not
    t_start=$SECONDS

    while (( (SECONDS - t_start) < 120 )); do
        if nmap $1 -PN -p ssh -oG - | grep -q '22/open/tcp'; then
            echo " This VM is Working Properly $2"
                return 0
        fi
        sleep 5
    done

    # we only get here if the loop exits without the port being open
    healthcheck_failed $2
    return 1
}

healthcheck_failed(){

    echo "Healthcheck of VM $1 FAILED"
}

healthcheck
```

We get output as :
[Output posted here](https://hastebin.com/qezogefuse.yaml)

IDK what is the issue, the script is not moving ahed, it gets stuck at the first IP :(

Comment: The solution given by @larsks works but for `10 seconds` (I suppose larsks did it because of testing). Just change `(SECONDS - t_start) < 10 ` to `(SECONDS - t_start) < 120`

Comment: Change your function name `nmap` to another one (e.g. `nmap_2` or what you want). Or in your `nmap` function use this: `if command nmap $1 -PN .....`. Note that I changed `if nmap` to `if command nmap` since with your current code the function is calling itself forever (recursively).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than checking the value of `SECONDS` during each loop iteration, record the value of `SECONDS` before the loop starts, then calculate the elapsed time on each loop iteration and check that. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

nmap_vm() {
    t_start=$SECONDS

    while (( (SECONDS - t_start) < 10 )); do
        if some_command; then
            echo "some_command succeeded"
            return 0
        fi

        sleep 1
    done

    # we only get here if the loop exits because the time expired
    echo "some_command failed"
    return 1
}

nmap_vm
```

Updating your code so that we only call `failed_vm` if we can't connect after 120 seconds, we would get something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

setup_vm() {
    echo setup vm
}

failed_vm() {
    echo failed vm
}

nmap_vm() {
    t_start=$SECONDS

    while (( (SECONDS - t_start) < 10 )); do
        # rather than nmap | egrep | awk, we can use nmap's "greppable" output and just look
        # for a specific fixed pattern
        if nmap $kernel_ipv4 -PN -p ssh -oG - | grep -q '22/open/tcp'; then
            setup_vm
            return 0
        fi

        # you don't necessarily need this delay in the loop but I like
        # to ensure a reasonable rate limit.
        sleep 1
    done

    # we only get here if the loop exits without the port being open
    failed_vm
    return 1
}
```